# Use image-set with multiple backgrounds in background-image

Tags: css

Hee all,

I want to use `background-image` in combination with multiple backgrounds and image-set. But the browser marks it as invalid CSS. This is my code.

```css
background-image: image-set(
      url(https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080) 1x,
      url(https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080) 2x
    ),
    image-set(
      url(https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF) 1x,
      url(https://via.placeholder.com/300/FF0000/FFFFFF) 2x
    );
```

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: the support is not yet good: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_background-image_image-set

Comment: Came across this question just now when trying to get a semi-transparent image background set to work with a background linear-gradient. It doesn't.